# Remove hash from specific asset files in webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm using Vuejs in a new project and I've added some images to the `assets` folder. I need an image to be referenceable also in `public/index.html`, but when I build the project the resulting filename includes an hash.

For instance I've `src/assets/logo.svg` and after build I've `dist/img/logo.e80b121e.svg`, but I want `dist/img/logo.svg`

Is there a way to remove the hash only for a specific file? I need the hash in the other assets. I'm configuring webpack with `vue.config.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `webpack config` vue cli generated four you if you move your asset in the `static` folder it will not get the hash.

Items from `assets` are getting hashed.

Comment: I reference the image also in a lot of vue components and I want to avoid to manually handle the path like in the documentation: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder

Comment: although that's the canonical way of including it, just doing /static/path/to/image will also work. Ofc, this depends on the value of <base href.

Comment: So I ended up setting `<base href="<%= BASE_URL %>">` in `index.html`, putting the file in the `/public/` folder and replacing the image path with `./logo.svg` in the components

Answer (score 1):

You need to get out the assets files from the entry, assuming that you has chunckhash configured (something like this: `output: {filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js"}`).
You could copy directly from source and add the assets to index.html using some of this webpack plugins:

- [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin)
- [HtmlWebpackExternalsPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-externals-plugin)

example:

```js
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackExternalsPlugin({
      externals: [
        {
          module: "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro",
          entry: "css/all.css",
        },
      ],
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts",
        to: "./vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts/",
      },
    ]),
  ]
```

Comment: I've used `CopyWebpackPlugin` and now there are both `logo.cd5607bc.svg` and `logo.svg`, how can I have only `logo.svg`?

Comment: Removing it from the `entry` ;)